# Sqlalchemy query with multiple joins including non direct many-to-many relationship

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a two models, AverageSoh and Datachunk that are not directly related to each other but are related through two different models. One of those relationships is many-to-many with an association table.

Models:

```py
class AveragedSohGps(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "averaged_soh_gps"
    __table_args__ = (
        db.UniqueConstraint(
            "timespan_id", "z_component_id", name="unique_tispan_per_station_in_avgsohgps"
        ),
    )

    id = db.Column("id", db.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    timespan_id = db.Column(
        "timespan_id", db.BigInteger, db.ForeignKey("timespan.id"), nullable=False
    )
    z_component_id = db.Column("z_component_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("component.id"))

    timespan = db.relationship("Timespan", foreign_keys=[timespan_id])
    z_component = db.relationship("Component", foreign_keys=[z_component_id])
    components = db.relationship("Component", secondary=association_table_averaged_soh_gps_components)

association_table_averaged_soh_gps_components = db.Table(
    "averaged_soh_gps_association_components",
    db.metadata,
    db.Column(
        "component_id", db.BigInteger, db.ForeignKey("component.id")
    ),
    db.Column("averaged_soh_gps_id", db.BigInteger, db.ForeignKey("averaged_soh_gps.id")),
    db.UniqueConstraint("component_id", "averaged_soh_gps_id"),

class Datachunk(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "datachunk"
    __table_args__ = (
        db.UniqueConstraint(
            "timespan_id",
            "component_id",
            "datachunk_params_id",
            name="unique_datachunk_per_timespan_per_station_per_processing",
        ),
    )

    id = db.Column("id", db.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    component_id = db.Column("component_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("component.id"), nullable=False)
    timespan_id = db.Column("timespan_id", db.BigInteger, db.ForeignKey("timespan.id"), nullable=False)

    timespan = db.relationship("Timespan", foreign_keys=[timespan_id], back_populates="datachunks")
    component = db.relationship("Component", foreign_keys=[component_id])


class Component(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "component"
    id = db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True)


class Timespan(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "timespan"
    datachunks = db.relationship("Datachunk")

    id = db.Column("id", db.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    datachunks = db.relationship("Datachunk")
```

As you can see, I have two non direct relationships between AveragedSohGps and Datachunk:

1. Datachunk.timespan_id == AveragedSohGps.timespan_id
2. Datachunk.component is within AveragedSohGps.components

I have no problem with joining on the timespan_id but I have no idea how to properly join on the many-to-many relationship around components.

The code that is being closes to be working:

```py
    datachunk1 = aliased(Datachunk)
    datachunk2 = aliased(Datachunk)

    cmp1 = aliased(Component)
    cmp2 = aliased(Component)
    cmp3 = aliased(Component)

    timespan1 = aliased(Timespan)

    avgsohgps1 = aliased(AveragedSohGps)
    avgsohgps2 = aliased(AveragedSohGps)
    avgsohgps3 = aliased(AveragedSohGps)
    
    query = (db.session.query(Datachunk, AveragedSohGps)
            .select_from(Datachunk)
            .join(Component, Datachunk.component)
            .join(cmp1, avgsohgps1.components)        
            .join(cmp2, avgsohgps2.z_component)         
            .join(Timespan, datachunk1.timespan)
            .join(timespan1, avgsohgps2.timespan)
         )


    res = query.limit(5).all()
    res[0][0].timespan_id # Datachunk.timespan_id = 49
    res[0][1].timespan_id # AvergagedSohGps.timespan_id = 49
    res[0][0].component_id # Datachunk.component_id = 6
    res[0][1].component_ids # AvergagedSohGps.component_ids = [7, 8, 9]
```

Also, much simpler query brings the same result:

```py
    query = (db.session.query(Datachunk, AveragedSohGps)
            .select_from(Datachunk)
            .join(AveragedSohGps, AveragedSohGps.timespan_id == Datachunk.timespan_id)
           )
```

I tried approaching it with association proxy but it doesn't work in query constructors.
I also tried joining using:

```
.join(avgsohgps1, avgsohgps1.components.contains(datachunk1.component))  # It expects a mapped instance, not a class
.join(avgsohgps1, avgsohgps1.components.has(datachunk1.component))  # Not implemented for collections
.join(avgsohgps1, avgsohgps1.components.any(datachunk1.component))  # AttributeError: 'Comparator' object has no attribute '_annotations'
```

Is there any way to properly join those two tables? To be honest I spent so much time trying to build that query that I am considering changing architecture of the application to give another joining point between the tables...